# Ending of Thelma

Tags: ending, thelma

In the movie [Thelma (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6304046/), if Thelma deeply (unconsciously) wants someone to disappear, something inside her can make that happen. In other words, she has the supernatural power to teleport someone.

Also, her powers portrayed in the movie is not consistent. It's not like Thelma enjoys suffering people but she does it unconsciously.

Examples (Spoilers ahead)

- She teleported her kid brother to a frozen lake/river under water
- She makes her friend/lover Anja disappear
- She makes her dad burn alive
- She makes her mom walk again

In the middle of the movie, Thelma makes Anja disappear and the movie runs for a solid 30 minutes without her. Thelma dad tries to cure her and for few moments even he decides to kill her.

Towards the end of the movie, Thelma dives deep into a lake and resurfaces in the swimming pool at school and she gets off the pool and finds Anja there and kisses her.

The above scene I understand, that Thelma loves Anja and she wants to be with her again and I thought that the above scene is all in her head, she's imagining it.

The movie ends with Thelma at school entrance sitting and Anja slowly comes from behind and hold Thelma and they both go into school.

What happened at the end? Did Thelma time travel? Is it one of her already existing powers?

Comment: http://horrorfreaknews.com/spoilers-thelma-ending-explained + http://montagesmagazine.com/2017/11/joachim-triers-thelma-2017-part-i-what-does-it-all-mean/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any time travel involved.

I interpreted the scene in which she dives into a lake and resurfaces at the swimming pool as not literal, but rather a dream.  Moments later she is back at the lake.

I interpret the ending as Thelma being even more powerful than she thought she was.

Rather than fleeing her powers, she embraces them, develops them, takes control of them.

Previously, she semi-consciously did bad stuff to people.  As a kid, she was jealous at her baby brother, first teleporting him to be underneath the sofa, then underneath the ice.  I believe the 6-year old Thelma actually does want that her brother vanishes.

But at the end, after the experience in which Anja disappears, her being told about her powers, and escaping from her father, she has more control of them.  She can make her mother walk, and more powerfully, she can make Anja appear again.  The film does not make clear whether Anjas reappearance is retroactive or not.

Similar themes are explored in the book [The Lathe of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven) by Ursula K. Le Guin.